# Xamarin Indie - how to purchase from xamarin website

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I cannot figure out for the life of me, how to update/purchase a Xamarin indie license, I had an ios and android indie license last year, and they have since expired.  I have updated one of my apps and am looking to build again, but cant becauase the xamarin ios license says my project is too big.

When I login to the Xamarin web page, I can sign in and see my license is out of date, I can even update my credit card info, however I see no way to purchase another Indie license.  When I click on update, it takes me to a page to Download Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio which I already have!!!

Please help meeeee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is now bundled with Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio. No licenses require.

Even the Community editions of both IDE's include it now. If you already have Visual Studio, you can just run the installer again and select Xamarin as a feature to install.

As for licensing issues, you should always contact Xamarin instead of asking the community. There is contact information on their web page.

Comment: Friend, I already have Xamarin installed, as I explained.  My issue is getting the error for license not allowed to build a file of x size.  I did not get this error before I updated, now that I have updated I cannot build.  I know you have to purchase the Indie edition to publish...  However I cannot find on the website how to purchase the Indie edition anymore...  I tried calling there customer service and it hung on my...   So I am seeking help here.

Comment: Remove your Xamarin Account

Comment: There is no Indie edition anymore. Everything is bundled with Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio. You don't have to purchase anything.

Comment: I logged out in Xamarin Studio and I am still getting the error.  /Users/ScaleAndRotate.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT9005: User code size, 3062320 bytes, is larger than 131072 bytes and requires a Indie (or higher) license. (MT9005) (ScaleAndRotate.iOS)

Comment: What version are you using? Sounds like an old one which has this logic...

Comment: Cheese thanks for all of your help!  I installed the latest version of Xamarin Studio and it is as you said, everything builds fine, and an Indie license is no longer needed.  If you would like to leave an answer I would be happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: I did however have one more question, why now that I have installed ios10 imulators and the latest version of Xcode, all of my pages appear about 200px above where they should start, meaning the top part of the pages is not seen behind a title bar, since it is moved up, have you heard of this or no the quickest remedy my friend ?

Comment: Please open a new question for that problem. However, I sounds a lot like edgesForExtendedLayout that you are not taking in account. Quick fix is to set them to none.

Comment: I tried to use EdgesForExtendedLayout, but that property is not available on a page, is that specifically for a View, do you know how it works?  ANywho I created a new question here,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575288/xamarin-and-ios-10-all-pages-moved-up-behind-title-bar